# Learning threads in Java, finding difficulty in Understanding some aspects

Tags: java, multithreading

I am learning Threads in Java online and I am a beginner, I am facing difficulty in understanding some concept. Can anyone help me?

Link I am learning from:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/616109/Java-Thread-Tutorial

Problem:

```
public class Core {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r0,r1;//pointers to a thread method
        r0=new FirstIteration("Danial"); //init Runnable, and pass arg to thread 1
        SecondIteration si=new SecondIteration();
        si.setArg("Pedram");// pass arg to thread 2

        r1=si; //<~~~ What is Happening here??

        Thread t0,t1;
        t0=new Thread(r0);
        t1=new Thread(r1);
        t0.start();
        t1.start();
        System.out.print("Threads started with args, nothing more!\n");
    }
}
```

EDIT: Code of FirstIteration and SceondIteration

```
class FirstIteration implements Runnable{
    public FirstIteration(String arg){
        //input arg for this class, but in fact input arg for this thread.
        this.arg=arg;
    }

    private String arg;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
        System.out.print("Hello from 1st. thread, my name is "+
            arg+"\n");//using the passed(arg) value
        }
    }
}

class SecondIteration implements Runnable{
    public void setArg(String arg){//pass arg either by constructors or methods.
        this.arg=arg;
    }

    String arg;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
            System.out.print("2)my arg is="+arg+", "+i+"\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and what is the question?

Comment: Please go through the code and you will get my question.

Comment: show us the code of FirstIteration and SecondIteration

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> r1=si; <~~~ What is Happening here??***

*Reference Assignment.*

You are creating a copy of reference `si` in `r1`. So, after that statement, both `r1` and `si` will refer to the same object.

```
            ______________________
si ------> |new SecondIteration();|   // You have 1 reference to this object
           ------------------------ 

r1 = si;  // Make Runnable reference `r1` point the same object that `si` refers

            ______________________
si ------> |new SecondIteration();|   // Now you have 2 reference to this object
           ------------------------
            ^
            |
r1 ----------
```

---

Actually, they could have simply done:

```
r1 = new SecondIteration();
```

instead of those two steps. But, as `setArg()` method is not declared in `Runnable` interface. So, to call it, you would have to do *typecasting* as below:

```
((SecondIteration)r1).setArg();
```

That might not be much readable, that is why they have probably divided that into two steps:

```
SecondIteration si = new SecondIteration();
si.setArg("Pedram"); 
r1=si;
```

Comment: But ri is a thread method pointer, thats what the author tells us. What is the significance of this assignment?

Comment: @user2613996. `r1` is a reference of type `Runnable`. And I don't understand, what you mean by *thread method pointer*?

Comment: @user2613996 there are no such things as _pointer to methods_ in java

Comment: That is where I got confused, if you carefully look at the authors code he has referenced it as thread method pointers. I got the logic of what you explained Thank you very much!

Comment: @user2613996 - Java has no method/function pointers. If the author says that they are he/she is wrong. `r0` and `r1` are simple object references.

Comment: @user2613996. If the first comment in that code, was written by author, that's plain wrong. Ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

```
r1=si; // <~~~ What is Happening here??***
```

Nothing really.

They are just assigning the object stored in local variable s1 to another local variable r1.

Not sure why, except maybe to "code to the interface" (r1 is a Runnable, no longer the more specific SecondIteration).

If I wanted to do that (hide the details of which Runnable implementation it is), I'd go a step further and use a local scope, so si goes away completely:

```
           Runnable r0=new FirstIteration("Danial");
           Thread t0=new Thread(r0); 

           Thread t1;
           {
              SecondIteration si=new SecondIteration();
              si.setArg("Pedram");// pass arg to thread 2
              t1 = new Thread(si);
           }


           t0.start();
           t1.start();
```

Comment: Thank You, I got the logic the confusing part was thread method pointers originally referenced by the author.

Answer (score 0):

Now the you will understand it.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
           Runnable r0 =new FirstIteration("Danial"); //init Runnable, and pass arg to thread 1
           SecondIteration s1=new SecondIteration();
           s1.setArg("Pedram");// pass arg to thread 2

           Thread t0 = new Thread(r0);
           Thread t1 = new Thread(s1);
           t0.start();
           t1.start();
           System.out.print("Threads started with args, nothing more!\n");
           }
```

Comment: Thanks man, I have got overwhelming response from this community!

Comment: `si.setArg` -> Where is `si`?

Comment: r1 = si is nothing but the object assignment to new referance

Comment: After your edit - `setArg()` method is not defined in `Runnable`. You would need to do a typecast.